# Child div inside dragable kendo window should not get scrolled

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I have a dragable, resizable kendo window, and inside that I want header to stay on top always and scrolling should be on wrapper only (which is working correct)  Heirarchy is following:

```
Kendo Wrapper
[   
  Parent Div
  {
    Header Div
    Body Div
  }
]
```

Hope this helps to understand and following is the css:

```
.wrapper
{
   position: absolute;
}
.parentDiv
{
   position: relative;
}
.headerDiv
{
   position: absolute;
}
.bodyDiv
{
   position: relative;
}
```

I am just putting relevant css, if you need any input then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
.headerDiv
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

to:

```
.headerDiv
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I have a draggable, resizable window, making it fixed wouldn't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? If the container is relative, everything positioned inside that container will be relative to that.

Comment: Header is going out of the wrapper grid. It is not scroll-able, it is fixed. But it should remain in the div. i.e. When width of the wrapper is less than header div, it is not honoring the width of parent div and is flowing out of it.

Comment: Okay, try adding `width: 100%` to the `.headerDiv` instead, that might help. It's hard to know what to suggest with such little code to work with and no example! :(